# The Address property on ChannelFactory.EndPoint was null. Endpoint must have a valid address

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service with the following configuration:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="LoginService.LoginBehavior" name="AuthenticationServices.Login">

        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBinding"
                  contract="AuthenticationServices.ILoginService">
          <identity>
```

To test the service I created a console application which consumes it.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoginService.LoginServiceClient client = new WCFDriver.LoginService.LoginServiceClient();
             client.ValidateUserID();
        }
```

Now when I call the service from console app it throws the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The Address property on C
hannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a vali
d Address specified.
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpoint e
ndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should specify address for service or for particularly endpoint (if there are more than one endpoints).

For service

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="LoginService.LoginBehavior" name="AuthenticationServices.Login">

<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBinding"
              contract="AuthenticationServices.ILoginService"/>
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5804/SimplePluginService.svc"/>
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

For endpoint

```
<endpoint address="myEndPoint" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBinding"
              contract="AuthenticationServices.ILoginService"/>
```

Endpoint's address will be added after base address.

If you host your WCF service using IIS, the base address will be taken from IIS's adjustments, not from `<baseAddresses>`